# what does it mean - "We all know that you are news"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> *“We all know that you are news - but are you king? King of the Jews?"*

*[(Jesus Christ Superstar music by Andrew Lloyd Webber and lyrics by Tim Rice)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_Christ_Superstar)*

What does the `news` word mean in this context?

**This meaning:**

> a person or thing considered interesting enough to be reported in the
>   news.
>   *"Chanel became the hottest news in fashion"*

**?** 
or may be a kind of slang of 60th?

Comment: Apparently, [*The killing of Lucas Emmet by George Orcutt **was** front page **news***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Orcutt+was+front-page+news%22) back in 1913. Regardless of whether it's adjectivally modified by something like ***front page***, the usage has been around a *long* time. What do you mean by "slang of 60th"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers hippy slang maybe

Comment: That's the *[nineteen] **sixties**,* not ***sixtieth***. Though I've no doubt it was a common enough meaning in the ***eighteen** sixties* and earlier.

Comment: "news" in this lyric could be roughly thought of as "a hot news item"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to [make the news](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-news)

means to do or be *something* that is worthy of being reported by an accredited news organization and usually results in people talking about the subject.

This is different than

> makeup the news

which is a currently followed topic about "false" news on the internet.

In your example

> We all know that you are news...

has the meaning that people have heard about Jesus and are talking about him: his teachings and his miracles

Sir Andrew might have used the phrase

> We have all heard about you...

but then it would not rhyme with "Jews".

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of 'news' in this context is pretty much on the mark - it's used in this context to describe someone who is famous or noteworthy in some fashion, i.e. to be famous enough to be newsworthy.

The scene in question is when Jesus is brought to Pontius Pilate after he has been betrayed by Judas.

> Pilate: Who is this broken man cluttering up my hallway? Who is this
>   unfortunate?
>
> Soldier: Someone Christ - king of the Jews
>
> Pilate: Oh so this is Jesus Christ, I am really quite surprised
>
> You
>   look so small - not a king at all
>
> We all know that you are news - but
>   are you king King of the Jews?

Pilate is saying that he recognises that people have heard of Jesus, and his reputation (presumably for his teachings and performing of miracles), but is questioning if he is really important enough to have earned the title 'king of the Jews'.